# In android and any mobile app, why is it launched in small sizes?

Tags: android, ios

For example, when I created an app in android.
I included a image file in the app. When I added the image, the app's
file size increased exactly as image size.
But my question is, many apps in google play apps includes so much images but
why do they have so small amount of file size?
Is it that they don't use picture format and using drawing api like canvas?

Comment: Try reducing image size before adding to app, i.e using image compression techniques or sites such as tinypng.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of them create a hidden file in storage... And then load their images from their...  Some developers also load image only in run-time. Suppose you have a webview behind a Layout. That WebView is only for loading a image. If you set OnClickListener on this Layout then it behaves like a image button. its a silly example :P

The best practice is to use Glide or Picasso to load image from server to your imageview.

https://github.com/bumptech/glide
http://square.github.io/picasso

Answer (score 1):

Because there these images are not being stored in app memory, In runtime they are downloading the images and displaying in the application. So There application size is not that much big.

But in your application you are storing images in drawable folder that is why your app size is getting increased upto as much image size is.